# Mod rewrite, url variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

How can I change this:

```
(1) http://test.com/?page=home
```

into this:

```
(2) http://test.com/home
```

I want it so that if you type (2) the server sends (1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /?page=home [L]
```

This allows the user to type either `home` or `home/`. Remove the `/?` if you don't want to allow the trailing `/`.

If you want it more dynamic and want any path like `/shop` to redirect to `http://test.com/?page=shop` then use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^page
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to slightly modify the above as it was including the / in the variable $1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^page
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```